# Send Request from server to ngrok server in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, server, get, ngrok

So I want to send a request from my server to NGROK server and it return null.
but when I check the URL, it return something.

I've tried so many ways, but it still doesn't work for me

this is my code

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
return $response;
```

I also tried request to another server (not NGROK) with same code, and it works. this is only happen on ngrok

Comment: What is '$url' ?

Comment: it's private url. ngrok url

Comment: It is working for me. ngrok version 3.4.0 , php curl 8.2.10-2ubuntu1